# getter function is not working when getline is used

Tags: c++, getline

I am using the getline to get string input from the user as shown below.

```
            cout << "Enter full name : ";
            cin >> fullname;
            cin.ignore();
            getline(cin, fullname);
```

getline is working correctly I am able to write full name with white space. But the problem is I am not able to get the fullname when getter function is used.

```
 if (strcmp(u[i]->getemail(), email) == 0) { // if entered email matches the email
                cout << "User name -->" << u[i]->getusername()<<endl;    //member details is displayed
                cout << "Full name -->" << u[i]->getfullname()<<endl;
                cout << "Password  -->" << u[i]->getpassword()<<endl;
                flag = true;
                break;
```

By the way below is my setter/getter functions for the variable fullname

```
  string User::getfullname()

{
    return fullname;
}

void User::setfullname(string fullname)

{
    fullname = fullname;
}
```

This is the constructor

```
  User::User(char* username, char* password, string infullname, char* email)
{                       //constructor
    strcpy(this->username, username);
    strcpy(this->password, password);
    setfullName(infullname);
    strcpy(this->email, email);
}
```

This is the Out put
https://www.dropbox.com/s/oya9wtswd3phq7o/error.jpg?dl=0

I am a newbie to C++ and would appreciate if you can point out the mistake.

Comment: could you upload your image directly here? Or even better copy paste the output here?

Comment: Welcome on stackoverflow. Please copy and paste the in- and output here (and format it so its readable). I think your question is too broad as to me it looks as if there would be tons of code behind it. Does the "getter" function work if getline is not used? Where does it come from?

Comment: Thanks for replying my doubts. I have checked. getter functions do not work even without getline

Comment: Why do you have the `cin >> fullname; cin.ignore();` before the `getline(cin, fullname);`? It looks to me as if you throw you input away first.

Comment: Thanks for the comment . Which way is correct..   just use  getline(cin,fullname);

Comment: You have a parameter with the same name as a member variable, so you're assigning to the parameter.

Comment: @malgmo956 yes, just call `getline(cin, fullname)` by itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reading your code, I think the problem might be coming from your `setter function`.

```
void User::setfullname(string fullname)
{
    fullname = fullname;
}
```

The function parameter and your class attribute share the same name. You need to identify by using the [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/this) keyword. Or change the function's parameter name.

Something of the likes of this:

```
void User::setFullName(string str)
{
    this->fullName = str;
}
```

Comment: User::User(char* username, char* password, string fullname, char* email)
{       //constructor
    strcpy(this->username, username);
    strcpy(this->password, password);
    setfullName(fullname);
    strcpy(this->email, email);
}

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.. Now it is working.. Thank you all.

Comment: It is because of constructor

Comment: value    setfullName(fullname);     change to another setfullName(infullname)    just in case                                                        This maybe helpful for another person too..